# Yii2: Passing dropdownlist selected value from _search to index

Tags: php, yii2, parameter-passing, dropdown, search-form

I have modified a year search form in _search.php into dropdownlist form, like this:

```
<?= echo $form->field($model, 'year')->label('Year')
->dropdownlist($model->getYearsList(), ['prompt'=>'-- Select All Years --',]) ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

When submitted, the gridview in index.php shows only rows according to selected year.

How do I display the selected year from _search.php into index.php such as

```
< div><?php echo $selectedyear; ?>< /div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from Query params, in index write below code.

```
$selectedyear=$_REQUEST['YourSearchModelName']['year'];
```

Edit : find class name from class id

```
$class_data=Class::find->where(['classid'=>$_REQUEST['YourSearchmodelName']['classid']])->one();
$classname=$class_data->classname
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh , That is works with year like the example above, but doesn't work with dropdownlist that has a relation (as foreign key), e.g.
**<?= echo $form->field($model, 'classid')->label('Class')**
**->dropdownlist(ArrayHelper::map(Class::find()**
**->all(),'classid','classname'), [ 'prompt'=>'-- select class --',]); ?>**
, It show only classid, not classname

Comment: You need to find classname from classid using query

Comment: Oh no, it works only when submit button is initiated, but when I access **proposal/index** for the first time (submit button is not initiated yet), it getting me error: **Undefined index: ProposalSearch**, what should I do @Rajesh?

Comment: The error is pointed in this code:
**$selectedyear=$_REQUEST['ProposalSearch']['year'];**

Comment: You are asking questions and quetions without acception the orignal answer or upvoting

Comment: I already upvote but it says: "thanks for feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"
I do apreciate you a lot for helping me, cool

Comment: you need to check by : isset($_REQUEST['ProposalSearch']['year']) that variable is there or not

Comment: yes, I just figure it out by checking isset($_REQUEST['ProposalSearch']['year']), and solved. But I can't solve this without your help, thanks @Rajesh